# Npm Error - Windows NT - How to resolve

Tags: node.js, npm

I get the following error when I try npm install :

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

What is wrong? I cant use nodejs < 0.10.36 or > 0.11

Comment: are you running this behind a corporate proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to point to a local registry or a registry behind the firewall

```
npm install --registry http://npm.myserver.com
```

Comment: Actually all of these are the right answers. Its due to multiple reasons! :)

Comment: http://npm.myserver.com is your npm server.  In many case, people build their own server and add all their dependencies there.  Dependency management is commonly used by having a server repository.  For example, Maven commonly uses Maven central to keep jar files for java dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

Change your location of cache. This will definitely work. By default NPM tries to pickup packages from cache and the default location is sometimes prohibited from reading.

npm config set cache C:\Dev\nodejs\npm-cache --global

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Updating npm solved the problem for me.
`npm install -g npm`

Answer (score 1):

### Culprit: Windows real time protection

Turn off the **real time protection** of Windows Defender (or any other anti-virus) and you will be good to go. I spent a lot of time finding this simple solution but it really works.

Comment: My Windows will not let me turn it off unless I install some other virus protection.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is a certificate expire issue with:

> npm registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

in stead run:

> npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

or else run:

> npm install -g npm

This helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Problem caused by my corporate proxy. Here is solution that worked for me:
In the

> "C:\Users\USERNAME"

Edit/Create

> .npmrc

file with next structure:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://192.168.10.10:1180/
https-proxy=http://192.168.10.10:1180/
strict-ssl=false
```

---

**use http regitstry** if https is blocked by your corporate proxy

Answer (score 0):

You are probably behind a proxy or firewall. Ref. [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8048).

To resolve the issue disable any firewall, proxy or antivirus that might interfere.

Comment: I am not under firewall. Proxy returned null config

Comment: What are you trying to install with npm? What is the contents of the package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Check the information at the log file generated at the same folder you issued the command:

```
cat npm-debug.log
```

In my case the error was related a mistake made during typing the content of the package.json:

```
verbose stack Error: Invalid version: "1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly occurs when you use any defender in windows or antivirus software. I have disabled Antivirus software and work right. 
if a problem does not solve then start your CMD administrator mode and you should point a local registry

```
npm install --registry http://npm.myserver.com
```